# GridView Binding with text and Image

Tags: android

I am parsing a xml File which returns an object containing name address and image. Now i want to display the text and image in a gridview but not in the same column.Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the gridView for just 2 columns then you might go with a tableLayout and add tableRows programatically. Something like :

```
<TableLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns:"0">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id=@+id/name />
        <ImageView
            android:id=@+id/image />
    </TableRow>
<TableLayout>
```

Comment: Trying to design 2 x 2 image with text, would you recommend table layout instead of grid?